# Adding Skeleton Loading to Component when firebase data is being loaded - VUEJS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Looking at adding a skeleton loading component while waiting for data to be loaded in from firestore. my code is below. I have created a skeleton loading component and have tried to use suspense to fallback but doesn't work with firebase API. Below is part of my template code.

```
        <div
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product.id"
          class="group relative rounded-none lg:px-10 lg:py-8"
        >
          <div
            class="rounded-none overflow-hidden bg-none aspect-h-2 aspect-w-0 h-15"
          >
            <img
              :src="product.imageSrc"
              :alt="product.imageAlt"
              class="h-[75px] object-center object-contain"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="pt-3 pb-4 text-start">
            <h3
              class="text-sm font-medium uppercase font-rubikreg text-gray-900"
            >
              <a :href="product.href">
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="absolute inset-0" />
                {{ product.name }}
              </a>
            </h3>
            <div class="mt-1 flex flex-col items-start">
              <p class="mt-0 text-xs font-rubikreg text-gray-500">
                Cheapest at
              </p>
              <img :src="product.svgSrc" class="h-3 mt-3" />
            </div>
            <p class="mt-4 text-lg font-medium font-rubik text-gray-900">
              From A${{ product.price }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and here is my firebase calls. Works fine just want to add skeleton loading prior to the data being loaded as there is a 2 sec delay.

```
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      onSnapshot(collection(db, "malesneakers") , (querySnapshot) => {
        const maleProducts = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const mlproducts = {
          id: doc.id,
          imageSrc: doc.data().imageSrc,
          name: doc.data().name,
          price: doc.data().price,
          svgSrc: doc.data().svgSrc,
          href: doc.data().href,
        }
        maleProducts.push(mlproducts)
  
        });
        products.value = maleProducts
        
      });
      
    });

    return {
      products,
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go here
https://skeleton-loader.web.app/
Design your content skeleton and it'll generate a single div to show the loader with it's needed CSS,
Then you should switch display between that generated single dev and your content.